# Compile C# Application for Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-xp

I try to compile a Program for Windows XP.

The problem I have now is, that the .exe Visual Studio creates is not executable under Windows XP.

It gives the message, that `.NET Framework 4.5 is not installed`. Because of that I compiled it for .NET 4.0, which is installed on the system.

My System:

- Windows 8.1 64 Bit
- Visual Studio 2013 Express (C#) / Visual Studio 2012 Express (C#) tried both

The other System:

- Windows XP
- .NET Framework 4 installed

My Configuration in VS:

- Target Framework: ".NET Framework 4"
- Target Platform: "x86"

I'm a little bit confused, please help.

Comment: What error message do you get after you compiled it for .net 4?

Comment: Are you sure it is not referencing any dlls that were built under the .Net 4.5 framework?

Comment: Are you sure that the version of .Net framework on client machine is 4.0 complete and not just the client profile?

Comment: This is a good first question, you are being careful about stating what your setup is an what you have tried. It needs just a little more explaination though - did the version compiled against 4.0 work? Is the problem just lack of 4.5?

Comment: I compiled without any warnings or errors. There are no DLLs that are not available for .NET 4. On the clients maschine is running a full installation of .NET 4 (not only the client profile).  The error message occurs on the clients PC that say: .NET 4.5 is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, why it didn's work xD

I used App.config to configure the applications database connection. But I just retransferred the .exe to the customer. In this configuration file was written the corresponding .NET Version. Cause of that the execution failed.

Thanks for your help.